# Codeigniter: Select box's selected value is not fetching when drop down in populated through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am having a country state city drop down (drop down of state and city is populated from ajax). Now i am not able to fetch the value of state and city selected, its showing blank when i fetch it like this `$this->input->post('state')`. Its going blank in database. Anyone can guide me from where i can fetch this value:

This is my controller code:

```
$data['country'] = $this->customer_model->getCountry();
```

This is in model:

```
public function getCountry()
{
    $arr=array();
    $query = $this->db->get('country');
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        $arr[$row['id']]=$row['country_name'];

    }
return $arr;    
}
```

This is in View:

```
<select class="form-control load_state" name="country">
       <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php foreach($country as $key=>$val){?>
           <option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $val;?></option>
        <?php }?>                   
</select>  

<div class="state_loader">                  
     <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">State</label>         
          <select class="form-control load_city" name="state">
            <option value="">Select State</option>                                            
         </select>
</div>
```

AJAX :

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(document).on("change",".load_state",function(){
        var id=jQuery(this).val();
         jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url("customer/loadState"); ?>',
                data:{'id':id},
                success:function(data){
                    jQuery('.state_loader').html(data);
                    $('.dataTables-example').dataTable();

                }
            });


        })
});
</script>
```

loadState() function in controller

```
public function loadState(){
$this->load->model('crmstaff/m_login');
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$data['state'] = $this->customer_model->getStateList($id);
$this->load->view('website/crmstaff/country/ajax_get_state', $data);
}
```

ajax_get_state.php

```
    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10"><select class="form-control load_city" name="billState">
                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                    <?php foreach($state as $key=>$val){?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $val;?></option>
                    <?php }?>

              </select>
```

when i print  it shows me the countryID and in ajax_get_city.php same code shows me the stateID, but dont know how to store and insert it in database.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: In your `loadState()` function, Why you use `$id=$_REQUEST['id'];` ? your request it using `POST` so it'll be `$id=$_POST['id'];` right ?

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam but this is fetching the id from $_REQUEST as well, what will be the difference?

Comment: alert(jQuery(this).val()); check what it show.

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST)` and your `$_REQUEST`, to get more information what's wrong...

Comment: @saty it is showing me the selected id of previous drop down

Comment: check your ajax status at your browser console.

Comment: @saty i am sorry i may sound weird, but i am a newbie to this can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: ok no worry tell me which browser you use?

Comment: google chrome i am using